# Creating a template file (xltx) from excel file (xlsx)

Tags: java, excel, templates, apache-poi, xlsx

I am trying to create an excel template file (xltx) from an existing excel file (xlsx).

I have already achieved it the other way round, so creating an excel file out of a template file.
But I need it the other way.

First I am clearing the sheets, to get a clean template file, but when I am saving it as a xltx, it shows up in my folder correctly but I cannot open it.
Only when i manually rename the file to (...).xlsx i can open the file.

Anyone knows how to create a xltx file from xlsx?
Is it even possible in code?

PS: IN JAVA

Thanks

Comment: When you say you are saving it as a .xltx - are you actually saving it as type "Excel Template" in the dialog box, or are you just changing the filename. You must change the file type in the dialog box. At that point Excel will change folders to the template folder

Comment: Yes I am changing the filename. Obviously that isnt enough. Thats the question if theres a way to change the file to a template file in code.

Comment: From xltx to xlsx you can make this://set content type to XLSX
            workbook.setWorkbookType(XSSFWorkbookType.XLSX);
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);

Comment: sorry: `workbook.setWorkbookType(XSSFWorkbookType.XLSX);
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `*.xlsx` file shall be saved as `*.xltx` then the content type for part name `/xl/workbook.xml` stored in `[Content_Types].xml` also must be changed to `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template.main+xml`. There is not an appropriate `XSSFWorkbookType` for `XLTX`. But this also can be done using the low level classes.

Example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

class ExcelWriteXLTX {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("ExcelTemplate.xltx") ) {

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
   Cell cell = sheet.createRow(0).createCell(0);
   cell.setCellValue("Content in template");
   // ...

   ((XSSFWorkbook)workbook).getPackagePart().setContentType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template.main+xml");
   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 ActiveWorkbook.saveas filename:=replace(activeworkbook.name,".xlsx",".xlst"),fileformat:=54
```

for no macros or

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Replace(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", ".xltm"), FileFormat:=53
```

if you have macros